# NotImplementedError: in FeatherS3 - ESP32-S3 Adafruit (BLE HID)

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy, error, adafruit

I am trying to upload a BLE HID code to FeatherS3 - ESP32-S3 Adafruit and get a NotImplementedError.

I have no idea how to proceed forward. Please help me on this. This code works perfectly on a NRF52 series chip.

Here is my code:

```
import time
import board
import digitalio
from adafruit_hid.keyboard import Keyboard
from adafruit_hid.keyboard_layout_us import KeyboardLayoutUS

import adafruit_ble
from adafruit_ble.advertising import Advertisement
from adafruit_ble.advertising.standard import ProvideServicesAdvertisement
from adafruit_ble.services.standard.hid import HIDService
from adafruit_ble.services.standard.device_info import DeviceInfoService

hid = HIDService()
device_info = DeviceInfoService(
    software_revision=adafruit_ble.__version__, manufacturer="Adafruit Industries"
)
advertisement = ProvideServicesAdvertisement(hid)
advertisement.appearance = 961
scan_response = Advertisement()

ble = adafruit_ble.BLERadio()
if ble.connected:
    for c in ble.connections:
        c.disconnect()

print("advertising")
ble.start_advertising(advertisement, scan_response)

k = Keyboard(hid.devices)
kl = KeyboardLayoutUS(k)
while True:
    while not ble.connected:
        pass
    while ble.connected:
        kl.write("x")
        time.sleep(1)
    ble.start_advertising(advertisement)
```

The error I am getting is attached. I am using the MU editor.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "code.py", line 22, in <module>
File "adafruit_ble/services/standard/hid.py", line 352, in __init__
File "adafruit_ble/services/__init__.py", line 49, in __init__
NotImplementedError:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found it. It is [not yet implemented](https://learn.adafruit.com/welcome-to-circuitpython/frequently-asked-questions#faq-3129409) for this board.